# Eclipse JDK 11 QName not found

Tags: eclipse

No matter what I try, Eclipse complains about QName not being found... It is indeed on the Classpath. It doesn't cause any other issues, I can compile and run, it just always shows that it can't find it.

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0)
Build id: 20180917-1800
OS: Mac OS X, v.10.14, x86_64 / cocoa
Java version: 11
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

All I did to make Eclipse to recognize it correctly was move the Java 11 Library up above the Maven Dependencies in Order of imports and Exports... I do not have an explanation as to why this corrected it or even a theory as to why but it works.

Comment: Sounds like you have another copy of the class on the classpath (and therefore in the unnamed module). But it is also contained in the JDK in module java.xml. I don't think a split package between these is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Some people who reported similar problems had a `module-info.java` created.
If you have done that:

- either remove it, if you don't need the module system's features
- or add a matching `requires java.xml;` statement to it (assuming you mean `javax.xml.namespace.QName`). Actually there should be a quickfix that offers to do that, if you use the qualified name in the code and have an error there.

(actually it sounds suspicous that you say you can actually compile and run your code - maybe the errors are just in places that are not used by your test run?

Comment: I have no module-info.java anywhere in my project. I can run everything just fine and code that uses QName works...

Comment: OK, this was just a wild guess because it sounded like similar problems. Then you'll need to provide more information. Can you show source code or upload a little standalone example project somewhere?